# PHP in_array isn't finding a value that is there

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array called $friend_array.  When I print_r($friend_array) it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 3,2,5 )
```

I also have a variable called $uid that is being pulled from the url.

On the page I'm testing, $uid has a value of 3 so it is in the array.

However, the following is saying that it isn't there:

```
if(in_array($uid, $friend_array)){
  $is_friend = true;
}else{
  $is_friend = false;
```

This always returns false.  I echo the $uid and it is 3.  I print the array and 3 is there.

What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you try in_array( $uid, $friend_array[0] )

Comment: Worth to mention: `$is_friend = in_array($uid, $friend_array)` is much more readable and does _exactly_ the same.

Comment: The values are coming from SQL.  I have a field called "friend_array" and it contains a comma separated list of values.  Do I need to do a foreach within my while loop?  I am terrible with arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array ( [0] => 3,2,5 )` means that the array element `0` is a string `3,2,5`, so, before you do an `is_array` check for the `$uid` so you have to first break that string into an array using `,` as a separator and then check for`$uid`:

```
// $friend_array contains as its first element a string that
// you want to make into the "real" friend array:
$friend_array = explode(',', $friend_array[0]);

if(in_array($uid, $friend_array)){
  $is_friend = true;
}else{
  $is_friend = false;
}
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/od0L7I)

Answer (score 5):

Output of

```
Array ( [0] => 3,2,5 )
```

... would be produced if the array was created by something like this:

```
$friend_array = array();
array_push($friend_array, '3,2,5');
print_r($friend_array);
```

Based on your question, I don't think this is what you meant to do.

If you want to add three values into the first three indexes of the array, do the following:

```
$friend_array = array();
array_push($friend_array, '3');
array_push($friend_array, '2');
array_push($friend_array, '5');
```

or, as a shorthand for array_push():

```
$friend_array = array();
$friend_array[] = '3';
$friend_array[] = '2';
$friend_array[] = '5';
```

Comment: This is really helpful...I think I need to read more about arrays and see if there's a more efficient way to do this.  Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your $friend_array is setup wrong. Each value of 3, 2, and 5 needs its own key in the array for in_array to work.

Example:

```
$friend_array[] = 3;
$friend_array[] = 2;
$firned_array[] = 5;
```

Your above if statement will then work correctly.